# APIM Gateway and protecting API with OAuth

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal, azure-api-management, azure-identity

I have API which is hosted in Azure. It is using Microsoft Identity platform for Authorization.  Now we need to integrate APIM Gateway for the API. APIM also provides OAuth Authorization.  So my question is should I configure OAuth for my API in APIM since Api would be deployed in APIM or I can continue to use Microsoft Identity platform which is doing its job.  So I am looking for benefits for using OAuth from APIM rather than throw Microsoft Identity.  In other words what would be difference and pros using OAuth vs Microsoft identity which also relies on OAuth?

Comment: I'm not sure about the question. But here you can a APIM Policy to validate the Authorization token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT

Answer (score 0):

Each API should validate a JWT access token on every request, then use the token's scopes and claims to authorize access to resources. This is sometimes called a zero trust architecture.

Another important requirement is to avoid revealing sensitive data in tokens, such as emails, to internet clients. The [phantom token pattern](https://curity.io/resources/learn/phantom-token-pattern/) has more info on this, and involves the use of an API gateway.

I would favour a solution where there is an API gateway in front of your APIs. This is a hosting best practice and also enables you to perform tasks such as cookie and token translation in the gateway.

APIM is one solution so I would favour that type of option if it improves your API security. There are other Azure options though, so it can be worth clarifying the types of things you want to do in gateways before choosing one. The [API Gateway Guides](https://curity.io/resources/guides/apigateway/) may give you some ideas.